# Spark Kafka streaming multiple partition window processing

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using spark kafka streaming using createDirectStream approach (Direct Approach)

also my requirement is to create window on stream but I have seen this in spark doc

"However, be aware that the one-to-one mapping between RDD partition and Kafka partition does not remain after any methods that shuffle or repartition, e.g. reduceByKey() or window()."

how can I solve this as my data is getting corrupted

Comment: Why is your data getting "corrupted"? What does that have to do with the one to one mapping?

Comment: I have gone through this comment in spark doc that i can't use window and reducebykey in Direct Approach (No Receivers)
I am thinking if this is causing the problem

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov

link:https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/streaming-kafka-integration.html

I just don't understand how repartition is not recommended as each partition is running in a separate thread 

correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You can definitely use `reduceByKey` and `window`. All the documentation says is that if you use them, the 1:1 relationship between kafka partition and spark partition breaks. Meaning, if you need to save offsets for exactly once semantics, you can no longer correlate between a given offsets and the msssages inside sparks partitions

Comment: val streams = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, inputTopic)
    .reduceByKeyAndWindow(reduceFunc, invReduceFunc, windowDuration, slideDuration, numPartitions, filterFunc)
    .map(_._2) .


   Then some transformation and saving to cassandra. 

If two Dstreams are running on a worker is there any chance of data corruption as  reduceByKeyAndWindow might be using offset range

Comment: I don't understand your question.